# Webpack image doesn't load 404

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-file-loader

Im working with react and webpack and I am trying to load images but getting 404.

```
const ImageComponent = ({ path }) => (
    <img src={path} />
);
```

The path is something like `assets/images/img.png`. Assets folder is near the `src` where all the application files is.

I tried with `webpack-file-loader` but I can't figure out how to solve the 404 issue.

here is my loader to `file-loader` I tried few options:

like this:

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
  },
```

this:

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/img'),
    ],
  },
```

this:

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/img'),
    ],
    options: {
      publicPath: '/',
      outputPath: 'assets/',
    },
  },
```

All the above options gave me the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you importing the image in your ImageComponent?

Comment: @MarekTakac no because the image is coming from parameter. I don't know what image to import.
I figure a way to make it work with `webpack-copy-plugin`, I think file loader is good only when you explicitly import the files. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Add **esModule: false** to the **options** for **file-loader** of images(jpeg,jpg,png,gif),

```
{
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      esModule: false,
      outputPath: 'assets/',
    },
}
```

Worked for me!

I got answer from: [404-not-found-webpack-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916085/404-not-found-webpack-image)